# Understand multiple linear regression coefficients

Tags: r, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

There are multiple posts asking for help in understanding the coefficients. Yet, I failed to find one that addresses the following.

```
set.seed(1)  # for reproducibility

## case 1: starting point 
dat1 <- data.frame(
  signal = c(rnorm(6, mean=100), rnorm(6)),
  condition = rep(c('trt', 'ctrl'), c(6, 6)),  # treatment, control
  experiment = factor(rep(1:2, each=3))
)
m1 <- lm(signal ~ 0 + experiment + condition, data=dat1)
round(coef(m1), 1)
#  experiment1  experiment2 conditiontrt 
#          0.4          0.7         99.4 

## case 2: second experiment is +10; nothing surprising here
dat2 <- within(dat1, signal <- ifelse(experiment=='2', signal + 10, signal))
m2 <- lm(signal ~ 0 + experiment + condition, data=dat2)
round(coef(m2), 1)
#  experiment1  experiment2 conditiontrt 
#          0.4         10.7         99.4 

## case 3: second experiment is +10 for control; why does experiment1 coef change?
dat3 <- within(dat1, signal <- ifelse(experiment=='2' & condition=='ctrl', signal + 10, signal))
m3 <- lm(signal ~ 0 + experiment + condition, data=dat3)
round(coef(m3), 1)
#  experiment1  experiment2 conditiontrt 
#          2.9          8.2         94.4
```

In case 3, why is there a change in the coefficient for experiment 1?

Comment: Because you enforce the estimate for `condition` to be the same within `experiment`, you do not allow them to interact. You'll notice that the parameter for `condition` *also* changes in case 3. If you were to add an interaction between the two effects you'll see it is that parameter that will absorb the shift almost entirely in case 3.

Comment: @PBulls: your comment looks like an answer, want to post it as such? Maybe add an explicit recommendation to search for the term "[interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_(statistics))"?

Comment: Aha, yes of course @PBulls. Re: condition also changes in case 3 -- that is very much expected, I would have been writing yet another post if that had not been the case :)